# Grails dependency and plugin version conflict

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, sendgrid

I am trying to figure out how to resolve version conflict between plugin and dependency in a grails project.

Here's what I am doing.

I am using [aws sdk plugin](https://github.com/grails-aws/grails-aws). The latest version of this plugin uses httpcore and httpclient 4.2 version. It is being used in many places so I don't want to change it.

```
plugins {
    compile ":aws-sdk:1.7.5"    
    ...
}
```

Now I am trying to integrate [sendgrid api](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java). This API has dependency on httpcore and httpclient 4.3.x

```
dependencies {        
    compile 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:2.0.0'  
    ...       
}
```

When I try to send email through sendgrid it gives NoClassDefFoundError. I know it is because of the older version(4.2) being used. I know this because I tried sendgrid API in a sample app and it workes fine with the same configuration.

I want both the library to use 4.3.x httpcore and httpclient instead of having two versions.

Any help or advise will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude `httpcore` and `httpclient` from `aws-sdk:1.7.5` plugin as

```
    compile ":aws-sdk:1.7.5" , {
        exclude 'httpcore'
        exclude 'httpclient'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, That is what i did, There was another problem someone from my team put these jar file in lib folder, I had to remove them too.